# How to get Base 64 string instead of imageURI in Phonegap while selecting image from Photo library

Tags: ios, cordova, base64

i am currently using below function to get image from photo library

```
function getImage() {
    // Retrieve image file location from specified source
    navigator.camera.getPicture(updatePhoto, function(message) {
                                alert('get picture failed');
                                },{
                                quality: 50,
                                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                                }
                                );

}

function updatePhoto(imageURI) {

    //console.log(imageURI);

}
```

But now i want base64 string not image URL !

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Change the following code from

```
destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
```

to

```
destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
```

please follow  this link [phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

Answer (score 1):

What we have found is that navigator.camera.getPicture() doesn't even exist inside Worklight.
However, navigator.device.capture.captureImage() works, and has the same signature seen in.
It ALWAYS returns a file URI, regardless of how the destination type is set. On iOS, it actually returns an array of images like this:
    [
        {
            "name": "photo_008.jpg",
            "fullPath": "/var/mobile/Applications/5585AC9F-27AF-46B1-AEA1-A2DFE01C218F/tmp/photo_008.jpg",
            "type": "image/jpeg",
            "lastModifiedDate": 1400008865000,
            "size": 1000708,
            "start": 0,
            "end": 0
        }
    ]

To convert this URI to base 64 yourself, you can follow this process:
1 - create a temporary, hidden canvas
2 - render the image onto the canvas
3 - export the base64-encoded image data from the canvas

A utility that can do this could look like this:

```
function encodeImageUri(imageUri)
{
    // My apologies as I can't recall where I found this snippet. But it works well!
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        c.width=this.width;
        c.height=this.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
    };
    img.src=imageUri;
    var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

    console.log("Encoded the data at " + imageUri + " to base64: " + dataURL);
    return dataURL;
}
```